# Keep/submit language config independently in page/request？

Tags: javascript, request, onbeforeunload

I am working on a web project that need to switch between different languages and load different data. Pages in different windows need to remember their language configs and do not affect other pages.

I was trying to add a `languageConfig` parameter to the request URL in `beforeunload()`.

Any ideas how to do it or other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Session variable to fix this problem.

Comment: Session can not distinguish setting in different page.

Comment: Yes, you can. Something like Session['Page1']['lang']='en' on Page1 and Session['Page2']['lang']='fr' on Page2.

Comment: Session[index][lang]='en'. Then user open another index page, with Session[index][lang]='fr'.Result in overwritten the first Session setting. and, Session[index1] Session[index2] does not sounds like a solution